# How to get user details using facebook connect

Tags: php, facebook

How can I get **firstname** and **last name** of facebook user while using f-connect?

I can login using api, but I couldn't get firstname and lastname of logged in user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to invoke users.getInfo. In PHP, you would do it like this:

```
$userId = 1234567;
$fb = new Facebook(FACEBOOK_API_KEY, FACEBOOK_SECRET);
$fb->api_client->users_getInfo($userId, 'name, pic_square, first_name');
```

You can check the [function's documentation here](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Users.getInfo).

Answer (score 4):

```
$client = new FacebookRestClient(API_KEY, SECRET_KEY, SESSION_KEY);
$userinfo = $client->users_getInfo($client->users_getLoggedInUser(), array('first_name','last_name'));
echo $userinfo[0]['first_name'] . ' ' . $userinfo[0]['last_name'];
```